# how to convert a table from excel to this matric in python (pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, collaborative-filtering

i want to build a collaborative user-base model and i have 20 users and 2234 items
i have table of 20 users that rated 2234 movies (most users didn't rate not all of them).
i have this sort of table :

```
 userId   movieId  Rating
    1       123      3.5
    1       36       2.2
    1       42       4.1
    2        .       3.1
    2        .        .
    3        .        .
    .        .        .
    .        .        .
    20       .        .
```

and I want to become like this :

[image]

i want to became a matric that have 20 user row and 2234 columns and the value is rating.

How can i do it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df.unstack('movieId')
```

This action shall move the row based indexes and formulate column indexes. Giving you the wanted result, Chris commentary also is a good sugestion. To your issue.